# jQuery if x checkboxes checked change link

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need a jQuery script. I have three chechboxes and two links. If all three checkboxes are checked, it show link 1. If only 1 or 2 checkboxes are checked, it show link 2.

```js
function toggleLink(checkBox){
  var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");
  if (checkBox.checked)
    link.style.display = "inline";
  else
    link.style.display = "none";

  var link = document.getElementById("dontagreeLink");

  if (checkBox.checked)
    link.style.display = "none";
  else
  link.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox1" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked onchange="toggleLink(this);"/>
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div> 

<div style="padding-top:100px;">
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked onchange="toggleLink(this);"/>
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div> 

<div style="padding-top:100px;">
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked onchange="toggleLink(this);"/>
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>  

<p>
  <a href="exmaple.com" id="agreeLink" style="display:none;">Jetzt bewerben!</a>
  <a href="none.com" id="dontagreeLink" style="display:inline;">Jetzt bewerben!</a>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is not a free coding service. We can help, but it's your job to work on this in first place. [Put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) first, then ask with a clear explanation and [MCV example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if applicable. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

  var checkboxCnt = 0;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      checkboxCnt++;
  });
  
  $('p').find('a').hide();

  if(checkboxCnt != 3){
    $('p').find('a#agreeLink').show();
  } else {
    $('p').find('a#dontagreeLink').show(); 
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox1" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked />
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div> 

<div style="padding-top:100px;">
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked />
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div> 

<div style="padding-top:100px;">
  <section title=".agreeCheckbox">
    <div class="agreeCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" unchecked />
      <label for="agreeCheckbox"></label>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>  

<p>
  <a href="exmaple.com" id="agreeLink" style="display:none;">Jetzt bewerben 1!</a>
  <a href="none.com" id="dontagreeLink" style="display:none;">Jetzt bewerben 2!</a>
</p>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Each checkbox will need a `name` attribute :

```
if ($('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked') && $('input[name="checkbox2"]:checked') && $('input[name="checkbox3"]:checked')) {
                //do stuff
            }
```